# Why does Call of Duty 4 crash to desktop when I enter multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

My new gaming PC is having trouble, it doesn't open COD4 into the multiplayer screen, as it is crashing before it even gets there.
Everytime I open up COD multiplayer it starts to run then it goes into a black screen and 10 seconds later it crashes and says look online for a solution.

Is this a firewall problem? A firewall prompt pops up sometimes when I try to open it and says 'allow access' and I do that, but it doesn't work. Is it a audio problem? I have tried everything except for check my audio configuration, sound, etc.

Comment: This happens when the game is cracked/pirated
Alot of pirated versions have missing multiplayer files
...

Comment: Do you own a standalone or Steam version?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem, and is caused by the game attempting to detect a microphone when there is none.

Go to the Control Panel, and then to Sound. At the top of the window, there should be a few tabs. Open the second one (labeled "Record"), and enable one of the devices there. You might need to right-click on empty space and check "Show disabled devices".

If you can, enable Stereo Mix. This is more reliable than enabling Line-In, for example.